# Pass Matlab parameters to a C program

Tags: matlab, shell, process, command-line-arguments, execution

I wrote a simple C program which takes a command line argument and displays that argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
if(argc<2){return 0;}
else{
    double x=atof(argv[1]);
    printf("%f\n",x);
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Now I want to run this program from within Matlab using the system() function:

```
>> x=3.14;

>> cmd=['/path/to/program/./test',x]

cmd =

/path/to/program/./test

>> [status,cmdout]=system(cmd)

status =

127


cmdout =

/bin/bash: /path/to/program/./test: No such file or directory
```

This doesn't seem to work when I try it. I really don't know how to solve this. I'm using a Mac. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This doesn't seem to work" is not very descriptive. Can you be a little more specific as to what exactly happens?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
x=3.14;
cmd=['/path/to/program/./test ',num2str(x)];
[status,cmdout]=system(cmd)
```

and '/path/to/program/' looks strange -- is test really located in /path/to/program/ ?

Comment: try without /path/to/program/

Comment: Kordowski /path/to/program/ is not real of course, but now I see why it went wrong, I didnt see the space after the ./test, so now it works when I add a space after ./test. Thanks!